# Change Which Shared Datasource an SSRS Report Uses (VS 2005)

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, datasource

We have a project that includes several SSRS reports. There is a report that uses a shared data source named "CT_Test". I need to create a report that is identical to that report, except that it has to use a shared data source named "CT_CTR". Both data sources already exist. I can copy/paste the existing report, but I can't find where to change the shared data source that the new copy is using. Can anyone help me out? I don't want to recreate the report from scratch if it can be avoided, it's complicated and it would take hours. I just need to select the CT_CTR shared data source in place of CT_Test.

Please note that I am working in Visual Studio 2005. I have no choice in the matter.

Comment: You should not copy the report if they are identical. You can deploy the report twice and configure a different Data Source for each report in the Report Manager.

Comment: Good point, and one that completely slipped past me. Thanks Jody!